# Swift 'Charts' pod warning

Tags: cocoapods, swift5, swiftcharts

When adding 'Charts' pod to my project I'm getting this warning :

> 'values' is deprecated: Use 'subscript(position:)' instead.

I am using Swift 5 xCode 10.2
Didn't manage to find any related info online.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is 'Charts' compliant with Swift 5 then? _Edit_, quick check says that the master branch is so maybe you need to build it yourself.

Comment: That's what I did and it worked, thanks. @JoakimDanielson